# Bind two different classes into one Datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I currently have 2 lists with different classes in them: `List<Player>` and `List<Monster>`.

I want to get these two lists in a single Datagrid as follows:[image]

The reason I need them to be in one Datagrid, is that I need to sort on Initiative, and show the order from high to low. The Datagrid also need to work with any number of players/monsters. The classes look as follows:

```
public partial class Player
    {
        public bool IsInParty { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Ac { get; set; }
        public string ArmorType { get; set; }
        public string[] Speed { get; set; }
        public int InitiativeBonus { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgVul { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgRes { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgImm { get; set; }
        public string[] CondImm { get; set; }
        public string[] Senses { get; set; }
        public string[] Languages { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Conditions { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }


    }
```

```
public partial class Monster
    {
        public BaseMonster Stats { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public List<int> Damage { get; set; }
        public bool IsOverhealed => Hp > Stats.MaxHp;
        public bool IsBloody => Hp <= Stats.MaxHp / 2.0;
        public bool IsNearDeath => Hp <= Stats.MaxHp / 4.0;
        public bool IsDead => Hp <= 0;
        public List<NameValuePair> Conditions { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public partial class BaseMonster
    {
        public int DefaultId { get; set; }
        public string DefaultName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Alignment { get; set; }
        public int Ac { get; set; }
        public string ArmorType { get; set; }
        public int MaxHp { get; set; }
        public string HitDice { get; set; }
        public string[] Speed { get; set; }
        public int Str { get; set; }
        public int Dex { get; set; }
        public int Con { get; set; }
        public int Int { get; set; }
        public int Wis { get; set; }
        public int Cha { get; set; }
        public string[] SavThrProf { get; set; }
        public string[] SkillProf { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgVul { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgRes { get; set; }
        public string[] DmgImm { get; set; }
        public string[] CondImm { get; set; }
        public string[] Senses { get; set; }
        public string[] Languages { get; set; }
        public string Challenge { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Traits { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] Actions { get; set; }
        public NameValuePair[] LegendaryActions { get; set; }
        public string LairActions { get; set; }
        public string RegionalEffects { get; set; }
    }
```

Because I am relatively new to front-end and xaml, I have a little trouble how to take on this problem. Currently I've managed to get the following with some test data:

[image]

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <DataGrid x:Name="creatureDatagrid">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="AC" Binding="{Binding Ac}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="HP" Binding="{Binding Hp}"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
<Grid/>
```

As you can see, some values work fine, but in this case AC is not working, because AC in found in `BaseMonster` in the `Monster` class

Comment: Multiple collections can be represented as a single list using CompositeCollection.

Comment: Why aren't you inheriting monster from basemonster?

Comment: In fact... Player and monster seem to have a lot in common. Why don't you have an abstract baseEntity class which has all those common properties and inherit player and monster from that?

Comment: @Andy Thank you Andy, this has helped a lot! I did not know about Inheritance, so thank you for the heads up, the problem is now solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DataGrid* columns are generated automatically based on the type of ItemsSource items. See [this blogpost](https://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-datagrid-auto-generate-columns) to get some more insights about this.

Since a *DataGrid* can only be bound to a single type / collection you first need to create a common interface which contains all common properties like

```
public interface ICreature
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    //Other common properties
}
```

If the items are not changed at runtime (otherwise use *ObservableCollections*), you can simply bind the DataGrid to the concatenated collections

```
public IEnumerable<ICreature> Creatures { get; } = Players.Concat(Monsters);
```

This will autogenerate all interface defined properties in your *DataGrid*. All additional properties, you need to define in XAML since they can't be autogenerated:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Creatures}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="CustomProperty" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <!-- More custom properties -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Use *PriorityBinding* for columns accessing different properties:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MixedProperty"
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="PlayersProperty"/>
            <Binding Path="MonstersProperty"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Note that autogeneration of columns also can be disabled to define all columns by your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the DataGrid's ItemsSource to a list with some common interface. So instead of binding to List<Player> and List<Monster>:

```
List<ITableEntry>
```

Or you can try to use an abstract class instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PriorityBinding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="AC">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Ac" />
            <Binding Path="Stats.Ac" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present a solution based on Template Selector:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TraitForMonsterTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Trait}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TraitForRestTemplate">
                    <TextBlock Text="None"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Type" Binding = "{Binding Type}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Trait">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                        <local:EntityTemplateSelector 
                            PlayerTemplate="{StaticResource TraitForRestTemplate}"
                            MonsterTemplate="{StaticResource TraitForMonsterTemplate}"
                            />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                    
                    
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

The Data Template Selector is :

```
public class EntityTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (item == null) return PlayerTemplate;
            if (item is Entity entity)
            {

                if (entity.Type == "Player")
                {
                    return PlayerTemplate;
                }
                if (entity.Type == "Monster")
                {
                    return MonsterTemplate;
                }
            }
            return PlayerTemplate;
        }
        public DataTemplate PlayerTemplate

        { get; set; }


        public DataTemplate MonsterTemplate

        { get; set; }
    }
```

Simple View Model to be used as an example :

```
public class MainViewModel : Binding
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Entities.Add(new Player());
            Entities.Add(new Monster());
        }
        public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; } = new List<Entity>();
        
    }
    public class Entity : Binding
    {
        string _type;
        public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Type)); }
        }
    }
    public class Monster : Entity
    {
        public Monster()
        {
            Type = "Monster";
            Trait = "Monster has a trait";
        }
        string _trait;
        public string Trait
        {
            get { return _trait; }
            set { _trait = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Trait)); }
        }
    }
    public class Player : Entity
    {
        public Player()
        {
            Type = "Player";
        }
        string _show;
        public string Show
        {
            get { return _show; }
            set { _show = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Show)); }
        }
    }
    public class Binding : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```